# Update one record in daily table from monthly

Tags: mysql, sql, vertica

I have two files one is daily file nd second is monthly file. Now daily files will get loaded into a table every day.

We get monthly file in next month 1st week(For Example In monthly file we have 1st Jan to 31st Jan data and we will receive this file in Feb 1st week).
After loading daily file data we will update monthly file ,Now I should add one column as status.

“ When order comes in daily or monthly feed, put status as BOOKED. When the order is not coming in monthly feed but is present in daily feed, you shall update the status as CANCELLED”

Who to write SQL for this??Any Suggestions.

Suppose in fact table we have

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------+ 
|order_id | booking_date | status | 
| 100 | 2017-02-10 | booked |
| 101 | 2017-02-12 | booked | 
+----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

In Monthly file

```
+----------+--------------------+ 
|order_id | booking_date |
|100 | 2017-02-10 | 
+-----------+-------------------+
```

I want result like this

```
+----------+--------------------+-------------+ 
|order_id | booking_date | status |
| 100 | 2017-02-10 | booked | 
| 101 | 2017-02-12 | cancelled|
```

Comment: Some sample data and desired result would be great

Comment: Suppose in fact table we have 

|order_id | booking_date  | status    |
|  100      | 2017-02-10     | booked  |
|  101      | 2017-02-12 | booked  |

In Monthly file

|order_id |  booking_date |
|100        |  2017-02-10    |

I want result like this

|order_id |  booking_date |  status     |
| 100       |   2017-02-10   |  booked   |
| 101       |   2017-02-12   | cancelled |

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward. Load your monthly file into the DB, then use this:

```
update MyTable
set status = 'Cancelled'
where Order_ID not in (select Order_ID from Monthly_File)
```

Comment: In Monthlyfile we will have only march month data right,if i use this query then it will update all remaning months data as cancelled.
For example when I get monthly file for march it should take only march data in MYtable

Comment: Finally Got it Thank q so much!!!! @JohnHC
update MYtable
set status='cancelled'
where (order_id,order_date)  not in 
(select order_id,order_date from Monthly file)